# why is it compulsory to use using namespace std in c++ language?

Tags: c++, using

This is a simple program and my question is to know why is it compulsory to use using namespace std ? why program is not complied without using this ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a , b , c , d;

    cout << "Enter First Value" <<endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter Second Value" <<endl;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Enter 1 to add values" << endl  << "Enter 2 to subtract values" <<endl  <<"Enter 3 to multiply values" <<endl ;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 1){    
        d = a + b;
        cout << "After Adding your answer is " << d << endl;
    }

    else if (c == 2){
        d = a - b;
        cout << "After Subtracting your answer is " << d << endl;
    }

    else if (c == 3){
        d = a * b;
        cout << "After Multiplication your answer is " << d << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "You Enter Invalid operation to perform";   
    }

    system("pause");  //buitin function to stop the comand screen.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's actually the opposite of compulsory. It's mainly used in C++ books for the sake of brevity. But in the real world, pulling the whole `namespace std` can cause serious headaches.

Comment: *why is it compulsory to use using namespace std* It isnt.

Comment: Bad practice to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: PLEASE READ THIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: *why program is not complied without using this ?* Did you try to remove it and look what is your compiler problem without it?

Answer (score 11):

> why is it compulsory to use using namespace std ?

**It isn't.**

In fact, [I would recommend *against* it](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

However, if you do not write `using namespace std`, then you need to fully qualify the names you use from the standard library. That means `std::string` instead of `string`, `std::cout` instead of `cout`, and so forth.

If your book does not tell you this already, then you need [a better book](//stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Note that you can put `using namespace std;` inside of a function, which may be more acceptable in some circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

You should not (but can) use

```
using namespace std;
```

You can use `std::` before each object from that namespace instead, e.g.:

```
std::cout << "Enter First Value" << std::endl;
std::cin >> a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally spoken, `using namespace` is not recommended since it uncontrolled imports everything from the name space into yours.

This may be okay, for very small tools or in a local scope but should not be done under no circumstances in header files you provide as an interface.

One convenient thing that might be ok, is to import some often used identifier into your (cpp file global - not header) namespace via.

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

Also note "Lightness Races in Orbit"'s link

Answer (score 0):

Without namespaces, you should care if your custom name conflicts with the included ones. The `using namespace` part of your code is a syntactical sweetener: you do not have to put the `std::` scopes for all occurences. Your code could be more readable, but set of your scopeless names are narrowed. Consider following example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char endl[] = "xy";
    std::cout << "[" << std::endl << "]";
    std::cout << "[" << endl << "]";
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use the name `endl` for custom purposes, you cannot have the `using namespace` directive, otherwise it would become ambiguous.

Comment: It's a bit more than syntactical sweetener actually; it opens up potential ambiguities that might otherwise not be there.

Comment: _"If you want to use the name endl for custom purposes..."_ Not really true; you'd write `::endl` (or, preferably, `myownnamespace::endl` (or avoid this name entirely!)).